Importing rembg in Celery Task breaks workers
I'm trying to use the rembg library in a Celery worker (Django), but once I import the library, the worker is exited prematurely:
objc[47160]: +[NSCharacterSet initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.


[2024-07-24 14:16:14,501: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-16' pid:47160 exited with 'signal 6 (SIGABRT)'
[2024-07-24 14:16:14,514: ERROR/MainProcess] Message: Error: {'signal': <Signal: task_failure providing_args={'traceback', 'einfo', 'kwargs', 'task_id', 'exception', 'args'}>, 'sender': <@task: assets.tasks.image_background.remove of oml at 0x1046a5c50>, 'task_id': '6219ab75-62b5-4d14-88ac-034d9fa71d45', 'exception': WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 15.'), 'args': [], 'kwargs': {}, 'traceback': 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/Users/cesarrodriguez/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1264, in mark_as_worker_lost\n    raise WorkerLostError(\nbilliard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 15.\n', 'einfo': <ExceptionInfo: ExceptionWithTraceback()>} Data: {}
[2024-07-24 14:16:14,514: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 15.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cesarrodriguez/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1264, in mark_as_worker_lost


I'm not sure if it's something related to multiprocessing Issues, have any thoughts?

It looks like the the error is not python related but a Mac M1 error instead.
After solving the log error:
[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called

Thanks to this issue
So, in summary, execute this command in your current bash session:
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES

